# How to fix CurrentUICulture when creating Threads

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, currentuiculture

I'm using the `CurrentUICulture` for Localization. This works pretty well until the UI Culture is queried in a different Thread.
So my question is how to fix the `CurrentUICulture` so that it is fix also when I create a new thread.

Currently I'm setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` in the very first line the application starts.

Thanks

Comment: How and when is that 'different' thread created?

Comment: It's due to a async webservice call done. But I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to set the CurrentUICulture everytime again and again...

Comment: Not sure if you've seen [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/39ab12ba-283e-4f82-945a-18f30d1366b0) already, but the answer may be that there's no way to set it for all child threads.

Comment: thx. I didn't see that question. looks if I can't get around setting the culture after every webservice call - or dispatching the call to the UI thread. Don't know which is the better solution for this. But anyway. thanks

Comment: Poking around some more, there's also this [How does .Net process get the Culture information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745439/how-does-net-process-get-the-culture-information).  Although the question seems to be about the process, answers are talking specifically about thread cultures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CurrentUICulture` is only relevant for loading  resources and so it should normally only matter to the GUI thread.

When you need it on another thread (I assume to load StringTable resources) then that might be a sign that something is wrong with your main architecture. It shouldn't normally happen.

But if you really need it, it should be possible with a few static variable to hold your CultureInfo and/or resource block.

Comment: Thanks Henk. The problem is, that I'm implementing a fault handling where I localize the error messages in response of a webservice call. So I'm definitly in another thread and I didn't want to set the UI Culture everytime. But I think I can't get around ...